# Using an intent to edit calendar event doesn't work

Tags: android, events, android-calendar

Ok, I read docs very precisely here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#update-event and its written something like this:

```
// Here is an example of an intent that sets a new title for a specified event and lets users edit the event in the Calendar.

long eventID = 208;
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, eventID);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT)
    .setData(uri)
    .putExtra(Events.TITLE, "My New Title");
startActivity(intent);
```

For me it doesn't work - it opens correct event, but it's NOT POSSIBLE to edit it - all fields are read only. Only fields what I can change are Timezone, and Reminder. Everything other is read only. Am I doing something wrong?

My API level is 14 (ICS)

Comment: What is your API level set at & do you have it with Google API's?

Comment: My phone API level is 14 (and also my app is coded for level 14) & I don't understand second part of your question...

Comment: When you select the API level for your project you will see two of each level. *Android 4.0 API 14* && *Google API's API 14*

Comment: @Asok there's no reason for the OP to install the google APIs - they're just broadcasting an intent...

Comment: And you're trying to edit an existing event, not create a new one, correct? It might just be a limitation...

Comment: yes, i'm trying to edit existing event, not creating new one. But I have many problem with calendar, whole api is not ideal...

Comment: I have filed a bug report: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39402

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I don't think you're doing anything wrong - I put together a basic implementation of the same thing via command line and the same restriction applies:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.EDIT --es title "New Title" content://com.android.calendar/events/1
```

I'm only able to edit the same fields you are - You might be better off doing a `ACTION_VIEW` and letting the user decide to edit (sorry I don't have a better answer for you, that's kind of annoying)

Comment: exactly same for me...But why docs says something else? Or they forgot to mention something very important (like many many times before) :)

Comment: Please vote for this bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39402

Comment: May 21, 2014. Identical issue in KitKat

Comment: It still there even in Lollypop and Marshmellow

Answer (score 3):

Workaround for this [problem](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39402): If you use Intent.ACTION_VIEW you'll at least get an activity in which you can hit the Edit button, after which you can edit the title and location and everything else (in the default calendar app anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can able edit an event in the only case you are an organizer of this event
so in your case, you a not the organizer